# Update state value of single object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have list of items where I want to display a loader and hide it upon completing certain action.

For example, here is my array items

```
[
  {
    "id": "69f8f183-b057-4db5-8c87-3020168307c5",
    "loading": null
  },
  {
    "id": "30d29489-0ba9-4e00-bc28-8ad34ff1a285",
    "loading": true
  },
  {
    "id": "5f54ebbd-d380-4a54-bb1d-fc6c76dd1b72",
    "loading": false
  }
]
```

I am adding item to array with `loading` value as `null` the reason is. I want to process as soon as the the state is updated, hence I am using `useEffect` hook to observe for any change, if any new item with `loading` value `null` is added, then I proceed for action.

My problem is, when I try to modify a single `loading` value to `false`, it gives me weird behaviour and set all `loading` value to `false`.

What I want to have it, when I change the loading value of a single item in array, then the UI should re-render only for the changed item.

If you want to have a look at fiddle with working example, here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/d8lh4-d8lh4

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The issue is, your `handleUpload` uses an outdated state `items` and when you call `setItems()` you basically delete all changes that happened in the 2000ms. Always use `setItems(items => ...)` when your new state depends on the previous state.

Comment: Let me try.....

Comment: @Thomas you are absolutely right. It works with your suggested approach. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple use this code:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
      setItems((existingItems) =>
        existingItems.map((item) =>
          item.id === newItem?.id ? { ...item, loading: false } : item
        )
      );
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Why? How is this code better than OPs code?

Comment: As pointed by @Thomas I was using outdated state item, with the approach suggested by him works. Here is my updated code `setItems((existingItems) =>  existingItems.map((item) => item.id === newItem?.id ? { ...item, loading: false } : item));` if you want to update your answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @I Yes, i update it, you can use what code you are good for you

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I think the issue is related to accessing the wrong value of `newItem` and `items` in setTimeout. Both of them can be solved by doing something similar to the one below.

```
 const handleUpload = newItem => {
  // set loading to false to new item after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(
    theNewItem => {
      setItems(exisitingItems =>
        exisitingItems.map(item =>
          item.id === theNewItem.id ? { ...item, loading: false } : theNewItem,
        ),
      );
    },
    2000,
    newItem,
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you using setTimeout for demonstration purposes or even in your final solution?

Comment: Oh sorry was late and didn't read the comments. Looks like someone has already pointed out something similar

Comment: It is for demonstration purpose. In actual I am making API call.

Answer (score 1):

You have [items] dependency in your **useEffect**, which is calling **setItems** in loop in your **handleUpload function**.

Comment: This is a valid point, but in its current version more like a comment than an "answer"; even an off-topic one.

Comment: I am already dealing with this situation. Upon calling `handleUpload` I am setting the `loading` flag back to false, this will trigger, useEffect one more time. However it won't enter `handleUpload` once again since the loading value is already set to false and it will stop the execution here.